# How to get a particular value in a pile ? (C++)

Tags: c++, stack

I would like to know how to get a particular value in a pile(/stack ? sorry I'm french :P). I have to unstack the summit of the pile, make it an int and get the [summit-int] value of the pile, so I can make it the new summit.

Thanks for the help :)

(Here's an example that will maybe make it clearer :

For example, with a pile [1 2 3 4 5 2] (in which the summit is on the right), the instruction will unstack i <- 2, which converts the pile [1 2 3 4 5], then copy the value 3, which is 2nd from the right and starting from 0, then stack it and, this, giving the final stack [1 2 3 4 5 3].)

Comment: French *pile* is indeed a stack. The most recent value is usually simply called the __top__ (not *summit*). Adding to the stack is often refered as a __push__ and removing them as a __pop__ (instead of unstack).

Answer (score 1):

Try `std::vector<int>`. It seems to be well-designed for what you are doing.
Use `back()` to get the value at the top of the stack, then `pop_back()` to remove it.
Use `stack[n]` to get a copy of the nth element of `stack`.

Comment: `pop_back()` does indeed remove the last value, but it returns nothing. To get the last value, you'd have to call `back()` first, which just checks the value, then `pop_back()` to actually remove it.

Comment: I must have been thinking of some other `pop()` function when I first wrote the answer. I have corrected the error. I don't know how to copy elements of an `std::stack` other than the "top" element.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the data structure *might* not be the best if you're going to be accessing it via index very often.

What you can do **if**, and possibly *only* if, you're using Visual Studio and Microsoft C++ implementation and you need to do it on occasion, you could tell `std::stack` to use a vector as a container as opposed to the default `std::deque` and use `_Get_container()` to gain access to it. `std::vector` allows indexed access. Here's an example that will print the first element in my stack.

```
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::stack<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >stringStack;
    stringStack.push("Hello");
    stringStack.push("World");
    std::cout << stringStack._Get_container()[0];
}
```

`Output: Hello`

Comment: Not a good solution. Who says the implementation provides a `_Get_container` method, anyway? You are right that a stack is the wrong data structure if indexed is needed, however.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: excellent point! I've been using VS too much.

Comment: You might want to edit your answer and mention that it depends on a VC implementation detail.